# OpenGL render .obj files with multiple material and textures

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm writing a parser for .obj files with multiple materials and groups (so I'm also parsing usemtl and material files). I can load and render the vertices. How do I deal with different textures and materials?

Do I render each material one by one or having a giant shader to choose ID? And how do I store different textures on the GPU buffer? (Currently I am using GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY but they must have the same size.

Comment: I group faces by materials and render each material separately got better performance this way instead of switching the textures again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to handle different materials, each object has the material specifications like ambient_color, diffuse_color, and specular_color. You simply, pass these values as `uniform` to fragment shader and render the object with different material specs.

Also, you can use 128 textures simultaneously in one fragment shader, so you can render an object with more than texture. But most of the time an object is made of groups and each group has just one texture, so you just need a `sampler2D` object in fragment shader, just the uniform values which you are passing for the texture will change.

Best way to handle this efficiently is to render the groups with the same texture together, so prevent lots of texture changes.